# Extract text without unique class in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do you extract a text 'Joanna K. Rowling' between tags that has no (unique) class using BeautifulSoup4?

```
        <li class="Feature-item">
            <span class="Feature-label"><span>Auteur</span></span>
            <span class="Feature-desc"><span >Joanne K. Rowling</span></span>
        </li>

        <li class="Feature-item">
            <span class="Feature-label"><span>Helden</span></span>
            <span class="Feature-desc"><span ><a href="url">Harry Potter</a></span></span>
        </li>

        <li class="Feature-item">
            <span class="Feature-label"><span>Uitgeverij</span></span>
            <span class="Feature-desc"><span ><a href="url">Bloomsbury Libri</a></span></span>
        </li>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In this case you may have to select by index, ore use `.find()` if you want the first item.

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<li class="Feature-item">
            <span class="Feature-label"><span>Auteur</span></span>
            <span class="Feature-desc"><span >Joanne K. Rowling</span></span>
        </li>

        <li class="Feature-item">
            <span class="Feature-label"><span>Helden</span></span>
            <span class="Feature-desc"><span ><a href="url">Harry Potter</a></span></span>
        </li>

        <li class="Feature-item">
            <span class="Feature-label"><span>Uitgeverij</span></span>
            <span class="Feature-desc"><span ><a href="url">Bloomsbury Libri</a></span></span>
        </li>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

names = soup.findAll('span', {'class':'Feature-desc'})

for name in names:
    name = name.find('span').get_text().strip()
    print(name)

#Output:
Joanne K. Rowling
Harry Potter
Bloomsbury Libri
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can save into dictionary by using `split`, because there is a `\n` before and after the text. `['\nAuteur\nJoanne K. Rowling\n', '\nHelden\nHarry Potter\n', '\nUitgeverij\nBloomsbury Libri\n']`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
        <li class="Feature-item">
            <span class="Feature-label"><span>Auteur</span></span>
            <span class="Feature-desc"><span >Joanne K. Rowling</span></span>
        </li>

        <li class="Feature-item">
            <span class="Feature-label"><span>Helden</span></span>
            <span class="Feature-desc"><span ><a href="url">Harry Potter</a></span></span>
        </li>

        <li class="Feature-item">
            <span class="Feature-label"><span>Uitgeverij</span></span>
            <span class="Feature-desc"><span ><a href="url">Bloomsbury Libri</a></span></span>
        </li>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

li_list = soup.find_all('li', {'class':'Feature-item'})

data_dict = {li.span.text:li.text.split("\n")[2] for li in li_list} 

print(data_dict)
# {'Auteur': 'Joanne K. Rowling', 'Uitgeverij': 'Bloomsbury Libri', 'Helden': 'Harry Potter'}
```